# Visiting count and IP address verification

Tags: php, mysql

I searched everywhere, any online tutorials, but they are all dated and badly composed. I was looking for a way to count visits to a particular post, but only unique visits via ip address.

I am not unfortunately an expert, I have tried some ways but without success.
So I asked how to do it?

I create a table in the database called "**views_post**" with the various fields: **ip_address, id_post, views_count**.

I should create insert or update queries that add +1 to the "views_count" field of the specified post ID. Let's verify if an IP address is already present, so it will not insert / update the table.

I do not know how to run it all, I did some tests but only put the first value but it does not update anything at the next visits.

Any advice is welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need  an update  .. you could simply add  each single access to a  table visit

```
  id_address,
  id_post,
  date_visit
```

and if you need  distinct count for post you could use count(distinct ip_address)  total or by date eg:

```
 select id_post, count(distinct ip_address) 
 froom my_table_visist
 group by id_post
```

or

```
 select date_visit, count(distinct ip_address) 
 froom my_table_visist
 group by date_visit
```